# Allow user to upload .MOV video files and show them on website

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ffmpeg, .mov

I want to allow users to upload .mov video files on the website but I those .mov files are not being played any browser. I don't want that user download any browser plugin to see that video.

- My website is made in Asp.Net MVC with C# as programming language.

P.S - .MP4 video files work perfectly without any issue.

Comment: Then use MP4 videos. Apple's MOV video format is not supported by any browsers. (Unless you force your users to install plugins.)

Comment: I need to support this format, cause most of people upload video from their iPhone which are in .mov format. So I can not restrict them to .MP4

Answer (score 2):

MOV files taken by phones will usually contain H.264 video and AAC audio. If so, you can quickly and losslessly wrap them as MP4, using FFmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -map 0 -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

(this will work with MP3 audio as well). In case the audio is uncompressed (pretty unlikely), you can run

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -map 0 -c copy -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: How to implement it with C# in asp.net?